# Convert PHP to Perl Checksum

Tags: php, perl, checksum

I Got problem when tried to convert PHP to Perl. These the code :

```
<form action="" method="post">
Hex: <input type="text" name="crc"> e.g : 08 13 4B 04 03 00 01 00 11
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></form>




 <?php
```

Function PHP

```
function crc($data) {
   $content = explode(' ',$data) ;
   $len = count($content) ;
   $n = 0 ;

   $crc = 0xFFFF;   
   while ($len > 0)
   {
      $crc ^= hexdec($content[$n]) ;
      for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++) {
         if ($crc & 1) $crc = ($crc >> 1) ^ 0x8408;
         else $crc >>= 1;
      }
      $n++ ;
      $len-- ;
   }

   return(~$crc);
}
```

If Not Empty

```
if (!empty($_POST["submit"])) 
{
    echo "Input = ".$_POST["crc"].'<br>';
    $crc = crc($_POST["crc"]) ;
```

Result

```
echo "<br>Result: <br>";
    echo "Dec = ".$crc.'<br>' ;
    echo 'Dec - hex = '.dechex($crc).'<br>' ;
    echo 'Checksum = '.str_replace('ffff','',dechex($crc)).'<br>' ; 

}
?>
```

It's about checksum. It's running well on PHP but not in perl.
Please give me solution.
Thanks.

Comment: So where is the Perl script?

Comment: Perl ≠ PHP. Show us what have you tried

Comment: and what the PHP code calculates for the example input

Comment: I think you're calculating CRC checksums the wrong way. Why don't you use [crc32](http://php.net/crc32)? It's no problem to transfer broken PHP code to broken Perl code, but probably that's not what you want.

Comment: Are you alive? Was this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned in a comment, it seems to me that you try to calculate [CRC checksums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). Your code looks wrong and I don't understand why you don't use PHP's [crc32](http://php.net/crc32) function.

Because you didn't provide your approach we can work with, I wrote a small [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/) web app in Perl. Note that I used the well-tested [Digest::CRC](http://p3rl.org/Digest::CRC) module instead of a half-assed wheel-reinventing DIY implementation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Digest::CRC;

# CRC helper
helper crc => sub {
    my ($self, $data) = @_;
    my $ctx = Digest::CRC->new(type => 'crc32', poly => 0x8408);
    $ctx->add($data);
    return $ctx->digest;
};

# just display the form
get '/' => 'form';

# calculate the CRC
post '/crc' => sub {
    my $self  = shift;

    # build data from hex string
   (my $input = $self->param('input_hex')) =~ s/\s+//g; # ignore whitespace
    my $bytes = pack 'H*', $input;

    # populate data for our template
    $self->stash(
        input   => $self->param('input_hex'),
        hex     => $input,
        bytes   => $bytes,
        crc     => $self->crc($bytes),
    );
};

# done
app->start;

__DATA__

@@ form.html.ep
% layout 'default';
% title 'form';
<form action="<%= url_for 'crc' %>" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="input_hex">Hex</label>:
        <input type="text" name="input_hex" id="input_hex">
        <small>(e.g : 08 13 4B 04 03 00 01 00 11)</small>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="calculate CRC sum!"></p>
</form>

@@ crc.html.ep
% layout 'default';
% title 'CRC';
<table>
    <tr><th>Input</th>              <td><%== $input %></td></tr>
    <tr><th>Input (cleaned up)</th> <td><%== $hex %></td></tr>
    <tr><th>Extracted data</th>     <td><%== $bytes %></td></tr>
    <tr><th>CRC32</th>              <td><%== $crc %></td></tr>
</table>

@@ layouts/default.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Solving berna maxim's problems: <%= title %></title>
<style type="text/css">th{text-align:right}</style></head><body>
%= content
</body></html>
```

[image]

From your code I saw that you wanted to use a special CRC generator polynomial (`0x8408`). If you just want to check some checksums without the need for a special generator polynomial, you could delete the `crc` helper and use an exported CRC function instead:

```
use Digest::CRC 'crc32';

...

    $self->stash(..., crc => crc32($bytes));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @bernamaxim You can express that this helped by [accepting and/or upvoting answers as well. Welcome to StackOverflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: if I have case like this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opengts/forums/forum/579835/topic/6157901 how to coding in perl? thanks

Comment: @bernamaxim If you want to add more details, edit the question. If you want help for another problem, ask a new question. If my answer helped you, upvote and accept. Welcome to StackOverflow.